# Sidekiq fake mode is not working on rails rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq

I am trying to test a job on my rails code I have the following

```
RSpec.describe MyJob, type: :job do

  it 'job in correct queue' do
    VCR.use_cassette('mycassette/type') do
      described_class.perform_later(id)
      assert_equal 1, described_class.jobs.size
    end
  end
end
```

The above gives me an error `undefined method jobs` I have tested and it seems that I am running on the correct mode,  `Sidekiq::Testing.fake?` gives me true

Answer (score 0):

`perform_later` means you're using ActiveJob instead of using Sidekiq directly, so you also have to use ActiveJob's testing helpers: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/TestHelper.html

```rb
assert_enqueued_jobs 1 do
  described_class.perform_later(id)
end
```

Alternatively you can remove ActiveJob entirely by changing your job definition from:

```rb
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :my_queue
  # ...
```

to:

```rb
class MyJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'my_queue'
  # ...
```